# How do I prevent a jGrowl message from displaying again when the page is refreshed?

Tags: jquery, jgrowl

I have spent some time searching but haven't been able to find an answer to this question.  When the user peforms some action on my site, a jGrowl message correctly displays.  However if the user then refreshes the page, the message unexpectedly redisplays.  Also when the user navigates away from the page and then presses the browser's back button, the jGrowl message unexpectedly displays.

I have set a breakpoint in the code and it only gets hit the first time when the jGrowl message is expected to display.  Refreshing the page doesn't cause the breakpoint to get hit.

So how do I prevent this unexpected behavior?  Thanks for your time.

I would think this is a problem that many people would need a solution for.

```
<#escape x as x?js_string>
$(function(){

    $("a[name=preview]").fancybox({type:'ajax'});

    // We use jGrowl for the popups that appear in the corner
    $.jGrowl.defaults.closer = false;
    <#if confirmMessage??>
        $("#jgrowlcontainer").jGrowl("${springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(confirmMessage)}");
    </#if>

    // Delete a program
    $('#deleteProgram').click(function(){
        $.fancybox.open('<p>Are you sure you want to delete this program?</p>'+
                        '<button id="deleteProgram">DELETE</button> <button id="deleteCancel">CANCEL</button>');
        return false;
    });
    $("body").on("click","button#deleteCancel",function(){
        $.fancybox.close();
    });
    $("body").on("click","button#deleteProgram",function(){
        $.fancybox.close();
        $('form').attr('action','/build/deleteProgram.html').submit();
        return false;
    });

});
</#escape>
```

Comment: Could you provide some of your code?

Comment: Is the problematic notification's "sticky" property set to false?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  When the page gets refreshed I actually can hit a breakpoint in a different method of the code.  This method sees that the old message still has a non-null value and adds the message to the model again which the front-end code then displays again.  To fix this I use a flag which gets set when an action is performed that should display a message.  Then I use this flag to conditionally add the message to the model.  Then the flag is reset.